# Why repo interface extending 2 other repo interfaces is not being wired in controller?

Tags: spring-data

I try to follow the documentation as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) but it doesn't seem to work because I get this error:

> Error creating bean with name 'memberRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.timewin.application.model.Member

this is the Member class:

```
public class Member {
    private String name;
    private List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<>();


    public Member() {

    }

    public Member(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public List<Activity> getActivities() {
        return activities;
    }

    public void setActivities(Activity activity) {
        getActivities().add(activity);
        System.out.println("Member: 'activities' of " + this.getName() + " was set to " + activity.getType());
        activity.update(this);
    }

}
```

These are the repository interfaces and implementation:

```
@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<Member, Float>, MemberRepositoryCustom{
}

public interface MemberRepositoryCustom {
    public void createMember(String memberName);
    public void addActivityToMember(Activity activity, String member);
    public void addMemberToActivity(String member, Activity activity);
}

@Repository
public class MemberRepositoryImpl implements MemberRepositoryCustom{
    //implementation here
}
```

and I try to autowire the `MemberRepository` in a controller:

```
@Autowired
MemberRepository memberRepository;
```

Answer (score 1):

`JpaRepository` supposed to operate with classes that are managed entities so if a `Member` class is a *reflection* of some DB table `member` then you must annotate it with `@Entity` and `@Table` (just as an `Activity` class)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member {
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @JoinColumn(name = "...", referencedColumnName="...")
    @OneToMany(...)
    private List<Activity> activities;

}
```

Here is a nice [reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html) how to work with entities
And also you have to adjust a config in order to work with this functionality:

```
@Configuration
/****/
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.timewin.application.repository")
@EntityScan("com.timewin.application.model")
/***/
public class AppConfig /**some extends***/{
}
```

BTW I believe that the name `model` is not a best choice for a package that holds entities because this name really often is used for holding some intermediate/DTO/input-output POJOs